# sort() doesn't work correctly in mozilla & opera

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i need to sort one array but it works correctly only in Chrome. in the mozilla specification i found this text but nevertheless can't fix this:

> "The elements of this array are sorted. The sort is not necessarily
>   stable (that is, elements that compare equal do not necessarily remain
>   in their original order). If comparefn is not undefined, it should be
>   a function that accepts two arguments x and y and returns a negative
>   value if x < y, zero if x = y, or a positive value if x > y."

and this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort  may be it will help you and me

this is my code

```
arr.sort(sortTrip); 

function sortTrip(a, b) {   

    if (a.to != b.from) return 1;
    if (a.to == b.from) return -1;

}
```

And this is the `arr`:

```
var arr = [
    {
        "from": "Moscow",
        "to": "Rome",
        "transport": "NSB Regiontog Train",
        "seat": "25"
    },
    {
        "from": "Oslo",
        "to": "Paris",
        "transport": "NSB Regiontog Train",
        "seat": "25"
    },
    {
        "from": "Helsinki",
        "to": "Tokio",
        "transport": "NSB Regiontog Train",
        "seat": "25"
    },
    {
        "from": "Tokio",
        "to": "Moscow",
        "transport": "NSB Regiontog Train",
        "seat": "25"
    },
    {
        "from": "Paris",
        "to": "New-York",
        "transport": "NSB Regiontog Train",
        "seat": "25"
    },
    {
        "from": "Rome",
        "to": "Oslo",
        "transport": "NSB Regiontog Train",
        "seat": "25"
    }
]
```

result must be

- Helsinki - Tokio
- Tokio - Moscow
- Moscow - Rome
- Rome - Oslo
- Oslo - Paris
- Paris - New-York

Comment: Care to provide a valid input and the different results you got?

Comment: certainly, different results in chrome and mozilla with opera

Comment: It clearly says that you need to return -1, 0 and 1. so when a.to == b.from it should be 0, and when a.to < b.from it should be -1 or 1 depending on what to and from are

Comment: @TheBrain "so when a.to == b.from it should be 0" -- What makes you think those should compare as equal?

Comment: @hvd, nothing. Just guessed since he didn't provide enough info.

Comment: @hvd: Those must be considered equal to have a valid compare-function leading to a defined sort. See my answer :-)

Comment: nope. well okay i just want sort this array. see updated post.

Comment: @RomaPerfilyev: Thanks for your test data. But what is the expected result?

Comment: @Bergi: updated post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My other answer explains why your sort does not work stable. This one will solve your actual problem :-)

You can't use a `sort` for this type of problem, where you want to construct a list of nodes from a (unordered) set of edges. Sorting an array is only applicable if you can *compare* two of the elements without additional data. Say you have only the two connections `Tokio - Moscow` and `Rome - Oslo`, you don't know which of them comes first (without contacting your plan, but you don't have that yet). In contrast, when comparing numbers you can easily and always tell that 5 is bigger than 3 (by computing the difference).

Instead, we need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12048098/1048572) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252219/1048572) - build a structure where we can easily access a station by name and insert connections directly when we encounter them during looping them, so that in the end we have a list of connections by station:

```
var map = {};
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var con = arr[i];
    map[con.from] = con;
}
```

So that we can now construct your route as some kind of linked list:

```
for (var from in map) {
    var connTo = map[from].to;
    if (connTo in map)
        map[from].next = map[connTo];
}
```

And find the start station by deleting all destinations from the map:

```
for (var from in map)
    for (var next = map[from]; next; next = next.next)
         delete map[next.to];
for (from in map) // there's only one key left
    var start = from; // "Helsinki"
```

Let's construct the route as an array of station names:

```
var route = [start],
    conn = map[start];
while (conn) {
    route.push(conn.to)
    conn = conn.next;
    // maybe delete conn.next as we don't need it any more
}
// route:
// ["Helsinki", "Tokio", "Moscow", "Rome", "Oslo", "Paris", "New-York"]
```

or the result which you want, the list of connections:

```
var arr = [];
for (var conn = map[start]; conn; conn = conn.next)
    arr.push(conn);
```

---

Having that plan, we even could now construct a compare-function to sort the original array:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    // compare the positions of the departure stations in the route
    return route.indexOf(a.from) - route.indexOf(b.from);
});
```

Comment: it's genious. really. thank you for this wonderful answer, your saving my brain in safety)

Comment: well i found i don't quite understand this fragment: `for (var from in map)
    for (var next = map[from]; next; next = next.next)
                 delete map[next.to];
for (from in map)
    var start = from;`  i want to understand how it works but confused at this wild cycle `for (var next = map[from]; next; next = next.next)`

Comment: may be i can find start place without deleting but with `if` which will find that name of the start place is not one of the name of the arrival place?

Comment: The first loop is like just `Object.values(map).forEach(function(conn){delete map[conn.to];})`. It doesn't work with a single-level loop as we might delete keys which we haven't iterated over yet. After that, we do `var start = Object.keys(map)[0];`

Comment: And yes, "*find that name of the start place which is not one of the name of the arrival place*" is exactly what we need to do here. Not sure whether there's an easier implementation, but I think it's hardly possible with a single `if`… maybe I better had built a doubly-linked-list, it would be simpler (and more obvious) there.

Answer (score 4):

> See also [Sorting in JavaScript: Should every compare function have a "return 0" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883421/1048572)

---

```
if (a.to != b.from) return 1;
if (a.to == b.from) return -1;
```

That's not a consistent compare function (violating the reflexivity, i.e. `compare(x, x) == 0`, for example). What do you expect it to do?

Citing the [ES5.1 spec on `sort`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.11):

> If `comparefn` is […] not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array, the behaviour of sort is implementation-defined.
>
> A function `comparefn` is a consistent comparison function for a set of values `S` if all of the requirements below are met for all values `a`, `b`, and `c` (possibly the same value) in the set `S`: The notation `a <CF b` means `comparefn(a,b) < 0`; `a =CF b` means `comparefn(a,b) = 0` (of either sign); and `a >CF b` means `comparefn(a,b) > 0`.
>
> Calling `comparefn(a,b)` always returns the same value `v` when given a specific pair of values `a` and `b` as its two arguments. Furthermore, `Type(v)` is Number, and `v` is not `NaN`. Note that this implies that exactly one of `a <CF b`, `a =CF b`, and `a >CF b` will be true for a given pair of `a` and `b`.
>
> - Calling `comparefn(a,b)` does not modify the this object.
> - `a =CF a` (reflexivity)
> - If `a =CF b`, then `b =CF a` (symmetry)
> - If `a =CF b` and `b =CF c`, then `a =CF c` (transitivity of `=CF`)
> - If `a <CF b` and `b <CF c`, then `a <CF c` (transitivity of `<CF`)
> - If `a >CF b` and `b >CF c`, then `a >CF c` (transitivity of `>CF`)
>
> NOTE: The above conditions are necessary and sufficient to ensure that `comparefn` divides the set `S` into equivalence classes and that these equivalence classes are totally ordered.

Comment: I think more than that, it' is not a valid comparefn(a,b) according to the spec since it does not hold reflexivity for example (http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.11) i.e. compareTo(a,a) isn't 0

Comment: This looks like it's shaping up to be an interesting answer. Just to help you out a little here is the implementation of sort in v8 Chrome https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/array.js (that's insertion sort for smaller arrays and QuickSort for larger ones), Spidermonkey uses Merge Sort https://github.com/funkaster/spidermonkey/blob/master/js/src/ds/Sort.h

Comment: @Benjamin: exactly. Also the transitivity of `>CF` is violated.

Comment: oh it's too hard. can you explain this on my example ?

Comment: A function that can define an order on a number of objects needs to have some properties. For example, if you compare an object with itself the function must return `0` - and yours doesn't, so the sort algorithm gets confused. On which criteria do you want to sort now?

Comment: @Bergi: it must be chain .to - .from, for example Helsinki - Tokio, Tokio - Moscow, Moscow - Rome, Rome - Oslo, Oslo - Paris, Paris - New-York

Comment: @Roma: I see. Unfortunately, chaining them is not sorting :-) See my other answer