# JS sort not sorting when given undefined

Tags: javascript, sorting

I can't figure out why the sort function doesn't sort the array containing undefined.

```
var sortBy = function(collection, iterator) {
    var newArr = map(collection, function(item, key, collection) {

        if (item === undefined, null) {
            return [undefined, undefined];

        } else {
            if (typeof(iterator) === 'string') {
                return [item, item[iterator]];

            } else {
                var results = iterator(item);
                return [item, results];
            }
        }
    });

    newArr.sort(function(a, b) { 
        return a[1] - b[1];
    });

    return map(newArr, function(item, key, collection) {
        return  item[0];
    });
};

var list = [4, 1, undefined, 3, 2];
sortBy(list, function(i) { return i; });
```

If i remove the undefined, the array sorts just fine.  With it, it doesn't sort at all. 
Thanks for your help! (PS I'm new to coding so any other tips/recs on this are welcome)

Comment: Maybe `if(item === undefined, null){` should be `if(item === undefined || item === null){`.

Comment: if(item==null) covers both null and undefined in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming the *map* function is something like:

```
function map(obj, fn) {
  var re = /^\d+$/;
  var arr = [];

  for (var p in obj) {
    if (re.test(p) && obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      arr.push(fn(obj[p], p, obj)); 
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

then in the sort function, the statement:

```
return a[1] - b[1];
```

will do things like:

```
4 - undefined => NaN
```

So the erroneous line in the iterator could be:

```
    if (item === undefined || item === null) {
        return [undefined, 0];
    }
```

or whatever value you wish *undefined* and *null* to be sorted using—*Infinity* perhaps?

Comment: thanks!  The map is _.map in underscore but written in JS for this project.  For var re, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (item === undefined, null)
> ```

does never fulfill - it's using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). You want `if (item == null)`, which will test for both `undefined` and `null`.

However, since your `iterator` in the example is the identity function, this bug does not matter and `newArr` looks as expected.

---

> ```
> return a[1] - b[1];
> ```

If one of the values is `undefined`, the result of the subtraction will be `NaN` - which is not a valid return value for a compare function. If such happens, the `sort` behavior is unspecified - it could be (implementation-dependent) anything from screwing up the order, not sorting at all or even never terminate. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892652/1048572) and [the relevant spec section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11).

So choose where you want to place `undefined` values in the result array, and put a comparable value for the desired position in your tuple (array). Maybe `Infinity` or `-Infinity`?

Comment: After thinking about it, perhaps `[null, Math.MAX_VALUE]` and `[undefined, Infinity]` so they sort per [*Array.prototype.sort*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11). :-)