# Sorting an object ascending order in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array object like this:

```
var obj = {
  a : [0, 25],
  b : [1, 33],
  c : [2, 66], 
  d : [3, 12],
  etc..
}
```

How can I sort it according to the second value of the array ? It should be like that after sorting:

```
var obj = {
  d : [3, 12],
  a : [0, 25],
  b : [1, 33], 
  c : [2, 66],
  etc..
}
```

I found a similar issue but it didnt help: [Sort by object key in descending order on Javascript/underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553155/sort-by-object-key-in-descending-order-on-javascript-underscore)

Comment: you can not sort the object's keys, but you can sort only the keys, if you like.

Comment: Object's keys cannot guarantee its indext

Comment: your expected result does not match the title of the post. do you need descending order (title) or ascending order (example)?

Comment: @Nina Scholz: Sorry my fault. It should be ascending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only sort the keys of an object.

```js
var obj = { a: [0, 25], b :[1, 33], c: [2, 66], d: [3, 12] },
    keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.sort(function (a, b) {
    return obj[a][1] - obj[b][1];
});

console.log(keys);
```

Comment: This way can guide me. Thank you.