# Differences in JS Array.Sort IE 11 vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with a custom sort function I have written. In Chrome and Firefox the sort is firing properly and my records switch as needed. The issue arises when I run the code in IE 11. Here is my example https://jsfiddle.net/azb90cgv/8/

From what it looks like to me is that IE11 is switching the values entered into the sort function.

With dataset [A,B,C,D] Chrome and FF sort with by the combinations (A,B)(B,C)(C,D) for me IE 11 is comparing the items as (B,A)(C,B)(D,C)

This is an issue because my line `return 1;` isnt flipping my records IE11 is expecting a -1 value.

My goal: I want the data ordered by sequence, and when there is a duplicate switch the original order of the items.
Am I overlooking something? Why is this running differently?

Comment: There's nothing in the spec that stipulates exactly how the sort process should proceed. Your comparison function is logically inconsistent, since it does not have transitivity.

Comment: That's one crazy sort function you've got there.

Comment: Ok so I have a array of objects, I am sorting by the Sequence value. The User is able to change these. I want to move the record from it's current location in the array to the new Sequence location the user entered, moving the rest of the records down. How else do I sort this?

Comment: can you add some example how the your sorting should work?

Comment: The dataset should be ordered by Ascending Seqeunce. And when two records have the same sequence, switch the records. So each time the Try It button is click IDs 2 and 3 should switch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting in JavaScript: Should every compare function have a “return 0” statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20892652/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need for a stable sort another property with the original order. This is used if two items have the same `Sequence`.

```js
var points = [{ id: 1, Sequence: 4 }, { id: 2, Sequence: 3 }, { id: 3, Sequence: 3 }, { id: 4, Sequence: 1 }]
    order = true;
points.forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.order = i;
});

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function () {
    points.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.Sequence - b.Sequence || (order ? a.order - b.order : b.order - a.order);
    });
    order = !order;
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(points, 0, 4);
}
```

```html
<button>Swap</button>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: "*when there is a duplicate switch the original order of the items*" suggests the OP wants `… || b.order - a.order`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With this idea I was able to get something working in all the browsers.