# JavaScript objects sorting

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Ive got an array of objects, something like this:

```
tab = [
{ top: true, i: 2, bottom: false },
{ top: true, i: 5, bottom: false },
{ top: true, i: 6, bottom: false },
{ top: false, i: 1, bottom: false },
{ top: false, i: 8, bottom: false },
{ top: false, i: 1, bottom: false },
{ top: false, i: 2, bottom: true },
{ top: false, i: 3, bottom: true },
{ top: false, i: 1, bottom: true },
{ top: true, i: 5, bottom: false }
]
```

And I want to sort it, lets say we have object A and B:

1. if top == true, put it at the top of the list
2. if A.i == B.i, put A and B next to each other no matter what
3. if bottom == true, put it at the end of list

So the array from above, sorted would look something like this:

```
{ top: true, i: 2, bottom: false },
{ top: false, i: 2, bottom: true },
{ top: true, i: 5, bottom: false },
{ top: true, i: 5, bottom: false },
{ top: true, i: 6, bottom: false },
{ top: false, i: 8, bottom: false },
{ top: false, i: 1, bottom: false },
{ top: false, i: 1, bottom: false },
{ top: false, i: 1, bottom: true },
{ top: false, i: 3, bottom: true }
```

Im using Array.sort, but I cant make it work and it drives me crazy, any idea?

EDIT: I see that the rules arent clear enough, so Ill try to be more specify now:

1. if A.i == B.i, put A and B next to each other no matter what
2. if top == true, put it at the top of the list
3. if bottom == true, put it at the end of list
4. A.top: true, A.bottom: true - impossible case
5. A.top: true, B.top: true, A.i != B.i - order doesnt matter, same with bottom
6. top has higher priority then botttom, so if A.top: true, B.bottom: true, A.i = B.i then we put them at the top

Comment: It would be good to post example code that produced the example of incorrect output.

Comment: `if A.i == B.i, put A and B next to each other no matter what` - shouldn't that be rule 1 then?

Comment: And how do you sort two items both with `top` true, but different `i`? Or can you have an item with `top` true and `bottom` true? Your sort doesn't seem to be fully defined.

Comment: Why is `{top: false, i: 2, bottom: false}` above `{ top: true, i: 5, bottom: false}`? Surely since `top: true` it should be *at the top of the list* (per rule 1)

Comment: @MattBurland …and also rule 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proposal with a single sort and an object for sort order. It uses a value as default value of `1e6`, big enough to be greater than the value of `i`. If not assigned, it uses the half value of it.

```js
var tab = [{ top: true, i: 2, bottom: false }, { top: true, i: 5, bottom: false }, { top: true, i: 6, bottom: false }, { top: false, i: 1, bottom: false }, { top: false, i: 8, bottom: false }, { top: false, i: 1, bottom: false }, { top: false, i: 2, bottom: true }, { top: false, i: 3, bottom: true }, { top: false, i: 1, bottom: true }, { top: true, i: 5, bottom: false }],
    object = { top: {}, bottom: {} };

tab.forEach(function (t) {
    object.top[t.i] = object.top[t.i] || 0.5e6;
    object.bottom[t.i] = object.bottom[t.i] || 0.5e6;
    if (t.top) {
        object.top[t.i] = t.i;
    }
    if (t.bottom) {
        object.bottom[t.i] = 1e6 + t.i;
    }
});

tab.sort(function (a, b) {
    return object.top[a.i] - object.top[b.i] || object.bottom[a.i] - object.bottom[b.i];
});
console.log(tab);
```

Comment: I like the solution and Im trying to adapt it to my scenario. Can you have a look at this: http://jsbin.com/bariminawu/edit?html,js,console,output ?

The only problem is with 777-444-111, it breaks rule number 6

Comment: @Pawel, i suggets to try with a bigger value, bigger than twice of the max value, you have. insert value like 1e10 or for the half 0.5e10 or 5e9. [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/venogakoju/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's built in sort method for arrays. It accepts a callback, which can be used to compare the items to determine the sort order. The callback is called with pairs of items from the array. If the first argument provided to the callback is to appear first, return a negative number, if it doesn't matter return 0, and if the second is to appear first return a positive number. In your case, the call would look something like this:

```js
var tab = [
    { top: true, i: 2, bottom: false },
    { top: true, i: 5, bottom: false },
    { top: true, i: 6, bottom: false },
    { top: false, i: 1, bottom: false },
    { top: false, i: 8, bottom: false },
    { top: false, i: 1, bottom: false },
    { top: false, i: 2, bottom: true },
    { top: false, i: 3, bottom: true },
    { top: false, i: 1, bottom: true },
    { top: true, i: 5, bottom: false }
];

var hasTop = {};
var hasBottom = {};

tab.forEach(function (t) {
    if (t.top) {
        hasTop[t.i] = true;
    }
    
    if (t.bottom) {
        hasBottom[t.i] = true;
    }
});

tab.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (hasTop[a.i] && hasTop[b.i]) {
        return a.i - b.i;
    } else if (hasTop[a.i] && !hasTop[b.i]) {
        return -1;
    } else if (!hasTop[a.i] && hasTop[b.i]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (hasBottom[a.i] && hasBottom[b.i]) {
        return a.i - b.i;
    } else if (hasBottom[a.i] && !hasBottom[b.i]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (!hasBottom[a.i] && hasBottom[b.i]) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

document.getElementById("foo").innerText = JSON.stringify(tab, null, 4);
```

```css
#foo {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
</div>
```

Also, be aware that the sort built-in sorts the array in place instead of creating a new sorted array.

EDIT:

In the original reply, I misunderstood the description of the rules, but after the update and more careful consideration I have figured out the problem. The sort order depends not just on the local properties of the two items, but whether any item with the same index (`i` property) has a `top` or `bottom` property which is true, a global property of the array. In order to handle this, you must make a pass through the data and record if there is any item with a `top` or `bottom` property which is true with the given index. There may be a clever way to do this while inside the sort callback, but I did not see one. Also, note that my original post got the sign of the return value of the sort callback wrong. It has been corrected in this edit.

Comment: [Don't forget to `return 0`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20883421/1048572) at the end

Comment: Btw, you can simplify that to `return a.i - b.i || a.top - b.top || b.bottom - a.bottom;`

Comment: I'll edit it to include the `return 0` at the end, good catch, but I think the "simplification", while more succinct, may be confusing for people not as familiar with JavaScript's short circuiting and type coercion.

Comment: Aren't you breaking rule 2? Depending on how literally we are supposed to take *no matter what*.

Comment: Yeah, I think the rules given don't match the example, hence the comment about the description. If OP updates the description I will try to fix my code, but right now I'm not sure what they actually need.

Comment: Just updated my rules so it is easier to understand what I mean.

Comment: Updated my comment and added a runnable example.

Comment: nice solution, but you can skip the else parts, because you return already. just go on with `if`. the last part does not need the else too.