# Sort javascript array null value always at bottom

Tags: javascript

Hey i am using slickgrid plugin and there i have function sortNumeric to sort data in order

```
function sorterNumeric(a, b) {
      var x = (isNaN(a[sortcol]) || a[sortcol] === "" || a[sortcol] === null) ? -99e+10 : parseFloat(a[sortcol]);
      var y = (isNaN(b[sortcol]) || b[sortcol] === "" || b[sortcol] === null) ? -99e+10 : parseFloat(b[sortcol]);
      return sortdir * (x === y ? 0 : (x > y ? 1 : -1));
    }
```

Can someone help me to extend this sorting, so null values comes always at last place.

Comment: please add the data as well.

Comment: By "always" you mean "regardless of `sortdir`"?

Comment: Instead of `-99e+10` (which might be the smallest number you can imagine), one should use `-Infinity`

Comment: by always i mean when you sort in asc should be 1,2,3 NULL at end or desc 5,4,3,2,1 NULL at the end also. Data are just some random numbers

Comment: i cant use answer  down i have to overwrite my function

Comment: do you have a flag for the sort direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the result of the comparison as value for the needed delta.

In SlickGrid, you get the sort order with the property `sortAsc` of the wanted `cols` to sort. then just use the closure over the sorting direction.

```js
function sortFn(sortAsc) {
    return function (a, b) {
        return (a[sortcol] === null) - (b[sortcol] === null) || (sortAsc || -1) * (a[sortcol] - b[sortcol]);
    }
}

var array = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 8 }, { a: null }, { a: 42 }, { a: null }],
    sortcol = 'a';

array.sort(sortFn(true));  // asc
console.log(array);

array.sort(sortFn(false)); // desc
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice! Very elegant solution with plain JavaScript.

Comment: can you help me to overwrite my function because is slickgrid plugin function

Comment: but there is one function to sort asc or desc

Comment: @vladimirProp, you could utilize the given sortorder of the wanted column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
var sortcol = "num";
var sortdir = -1;

function sorterNumeric(a, b) {
    var x = (isNaN(a[sortcol]) || !a[sortcol]) ? 99e+10 * sortdir : parseFloat(a[sortcol]);
    var y = (isNaN(b[sortcol]) || !b[sortcol]) ? 99e+10 * sortdir : parseFloat(b[sortcol]);
    return x > y ? 1 * sortdir : -1 * sortdir;
}

var arr = [{ num: 1 }, { num: 3 }, { num: null }, { num: 7 }, { num: 2 } ]
```

Comment: [Don't forget to `return 0`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20883421/1048572)!

Comment: where to return 0

Comment: please don't just show the code. give explanation as how it works