# Jquery array sorting not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Here is my array and i am trying to sort it. But it is not working as expected. i want to sort the name as descending.. How can i do it ?

```js
var d = '{"success":"1","message":[{"_id":"591b39df358f1d1f843231d1","area":"chennai","food":"idly","name":"saravana bavan","__v":0},{"_id":"591b39e0358f1d1f843231d2","area":"Dindigul","food":"Dosa","name":"Kattu Briyani","__v":0},{"_id":"591b39df358f1d1f843231d4","area":"Tirupur","food":"Poori","name":"French Loaf","__v":0}]}';
console.log(d);
var results = jQuery.parseJSON(d);
console.log(results.message);
results.message.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.name- a.name;
});
console.log(results.message);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1275o6g/1)

Comment: you can have demo using SO `<>`

Comment: If you want to sort the names descending, then why are you sorting by area?!

Comment: @Bergi, Sorry it was a typo, changing it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform mathematical operations on strings.

```
results.message.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (b.name > a.name) { return 1 }
    else if (b.name < a.name) { return -1 }
    else { return 0 }
});
```

As @bergi mentioned in a comment below. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572) explains the problem in depth.

Comment: is it just me or this answer is from the link given by @Bergi

Comment: Just checked. Its basically the same thing, but there's not really another way to do this is there? I'll add the link to my answer.

Comment: How about `return b.name.localeCompare(a.name)`

Comment: @guradio Na, I didn't do anything with names in my answer there (which specifically explains the problem of never returning negative values). Of course the correct approach is always the same :-)

Comment: @Phil Better not, that treats special characters differently

Answer (score -1):

just change your comparison function as follows:

```
var d = '{"success":"1","message":[{"_id":"591b39df358f1d1f843231d1","area":"chennai","food":"idly","name":"saravana bavan","__v":0},{"_id":"591b39e0358f1d1f843231d2","area":"Dindigul","food":"Dosa","name":"Kattu Briyani","__v":0},{"_id":"591b39df358f1d1f843231d4","area":"Tirupur","food":"Poori","name":"French Loaf","__v":0}]}';
console.log(d);
var results = jQuery.parseJSON(d);
console.log(results.message);
results.message.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.name.toLowerCase() > a.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
});
console.log(results.message);
```

Comment: [Don't forget to return `0` when appropriate!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20892652/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi it should be slower right?, but i'm just curious, have someone benchmark it? how much slower is a 'swap' compared to an 'extra if' statement?

Comment: I don't care about speed when correctness is impaired. Not returning `0` does not work with duplicate values in the sorted array.

Comment: @Bergi in your linked answer, the correctness depends on the algorithm used, but there is no problem with it, even if they got swapped, the values are the same, so it does not result in an incorrect result, only an excess swapping, but that is comparable to an excess if statement