# Filter and reduce object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not really sure on how to do this, I have an object that contains several objects. It looks like this :

```
object {
    apps: {
       apps1: {
           date: "2017-07-05T17:13:53.956Z",
           status: false
              }
          },
       apps2: {
            date: "2017-07-11T15:15:39.027Z",
            status: false
              },
       apps3: {
            date: "2017-07-11T15:36:33.063Z",
            status: true
              }
       }
```

Now I wanted to sort them by date first which is working :

```
function getAppStatus(user) {
  let newArr = Object.keys(user.apps).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return user.apps[a].date > user.apps[b].date ? a : b;
  });
```

But I only want to sort the one that have `status === false` so basically I want to delete the apps3 if the status is true and then sort the rest by date.

Any ideas ?

thanks !

Comment: You want to filter/sort the items, by using reduce? First use filter, and then use sort.

Comment: Do you want to get the key of the first date, or do you actually want to sort anything (which requires an array btw)?

Comment: @Bergi I just want to sort by date the ones with a status : false. I can already sort them by date but I still have the one with status : true in the final object

Comment: First splice the ones with status === false, then use your sort method on the latest array.

Comment: @NischalKumarBC No need for splice if the OP used filter.

Comment: @pkerckho is the nesting of apps1 wrong in your data structure. Because unless it is. I do not understand how the selected answer works for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
var newArr = Object.keys(user.apps)
      // convert the object to an array by key.
      .map(function (key) { return user.apps[key]; })
      // get apps with status === false.
      .filter(function (app) { return !app.status; })
      // sort by date. Since the date is stored as a string, use localeCompare.
      .sort(function (a1, a2) { return a1.date.localeCompare(a2.date)); });
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to this?

Comment: [Don't forget to return `0` when necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883421/1048572)

Comment: It works.  Use this object:  var user = {
  apps : {
    apps1: {
           date: "2017-07-05T17:13:53.956Z",
           status: false
              },
       apps2: {
            date: "2017-07-11T15:15:39.027Z",
            status: false
              },
       apps3: {
            date: "2017-07-11T15:36:33.063Z",
            status: true
              }
       }
  }

Comment: @Bergi thanks for that, I switched it to `localeCompare` to avoid writing the sort function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I was a pain to solve by myself

Comment: @Bergi how does this answer work when apps1 is nested in apps and apps2 and app3 is not?

Comment: @Arrow It would not work? Whatever structure you have, you need to get them in an array. But why are you asking me that?

Comment: @Bergi from your comment it seemed like you approved of this answer.  My bad    :- )