# compareFunction for Array.sort at Chrome that will do nothing

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I need a `compareFunction` that will be used as below and the array will not change at all.
 The code I provide works great for Mozilla but not for Chrome.
Running the snippet at Chrome you will see that the order for the `array2` (more than 10 objects) is changed.
 How to achieve preserving order also for Chrome?
I don't need any sorting since I already know my array will be sorted.

```js
function compareFunction(direction, a, b){
  return 0;
}

var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'x',10];
array1.sort((a,b)=>{return compareFunction.call(null, 'asc', a, b)});
console.log(array1.toString());

var array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'x',10,11];
array2.sort((a,b)=>{return compareFunction.call(null, 'asc', a, b)});
console.log(array2.toString());
```

Comment: "The sort is not necessarily stable." I think the only way to keep sorted array sorted is to provide comparator that has been used to sort the array. And even this wont guarantee the order of "equal" items to be the same.

Comment: Order in which a and b are chosen in `comparator` function is **implementation dependent**. On chrome, it will do quick sort if the length of items are more than 10, which is why it picks up 6 before 2 for comparison.

Comment: See [Sorting in JavaScript: Should every compare function have a “return 0” statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883421/sorting-in-javascript-should-every-compare-function-have-a-return-0-statement)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Sort is not stable, true. I am just asking if it is possible somehow given the occasion I provided to create a 'compareFunction' that will actually do no sorting but keeping objects as they already are.

Comment: @Olezt The fact that sorting is not stable makes it impossible. Solution provided by gurvinder is less than ideal. First of all it might fail if you have equal items. Then `indexOf` is `O(n)` making entire sorting to be `O(n^2*log n)` which might be a problem on large lists.

Comment: Given the circumstances I gave, no real solution came up (Still looking for one if exists).
What I did to overcome this problem was to extend the class that implemented `sort()` using `Array.protorype.sort` and implement one that did not, just returning the array as is.

Answer (score 0):

Order in which `a` and `b` are chosen in *comparator function* is **implementation dependent**. In chrome, it does quick sort if the length of items are more than `10`, which is why it picks up `6` before `2` for comparison.

Instead of `this`, pass the **actual array** and compare the index positions of the parameters in the original array.

You need to **make a copy of original array** by doing `array.slice()` so that it is not mutated while sorting.

```js
function compareFunction(a,b){
  return this.indexOf(a) - this.indexOf(b);
}

var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'x',10];
array1 = array1.slice().sort(function(a,b){return compareFunction.call(array1,a,b)});
console.log(array1);

var array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'x',10,11];
array2 = array2.slice().sort(function(a,b){return compareFunction.call(array2,a,b)}); 
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: This would a nice solution but in my case I don't have access to do this. This is done by a library I use and they actually pass null there. Thank you for your time though. This may help someone else.

Comment: @Olezt Out of curiosity, do you **really** have to use a comparator function, given that you are not modifying anything?

Comment: The flow will go through this anyway. If I don't provide a function, they use their own. I actually do my sorting on backend but I use their provided variables etc (angular4 ng2-smart-table) which leads to this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var arr1 = [1,2],
    arr2 = [1,2,3],
    arr3 = [1,2,3],
    arr4 = [3,2,1];

function compare(a, b) {

  if(a.length != b.length) return false;

  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] != b[i]) return false;
  }

  return true;

}


console.log(compare(arr1, arr2)); // false
console.log(compare(arr2, arr3)); // true
console.log(compare(arr3, arr4)); // false
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but this is not even close to what I am looking/asking for.