# Sorting strings in descending order in Javascript (Most efficiently)?

Tags: javascript, sorting

W3CSchools has this example:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort();
fruits.reverse();
```

Is this the most efficient way to sort strings in descending order in Javascript?

### Update

One of the answers is using `localeCompare`.  Just curious whether if we do `reverse()`, will that work for all locales (Maybe this is a separate question - Just let me know in the comments)?

Comment: By what measure of efficiency?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly

Comment: `.sort()` and `.reverse()` is already the most efficient way.

Comment: `.sort((a, b) => -(a>b)||+(a<b))`

Comment: `reverse()` doesn't care about the locales, it only modifies the indexes of the array in reverse order

Comment: as I said in my answer using just `sort` and `reverse` a > Z and Á > Z, that is completely wrong. Try this `["a","b","c","A","B","Z"]`, the result is `[ 'c', 'b', 'a', 'Z', 'B', 'A' ]` : /

Comment: So would it be fair to say that we should use reverse when all the characters are lower case, and localeCompare otherwise?

Comment: So for example API wise we may have two methods `sortLowercaseDescending()` and `sortStringDescending()` ...

Comment: Provided a typescript sorting implementation here (If anyone has any improvement feedback that would be great): https://github.com/fireflysemantics/collections/blob/master/src/index.ts

Answer (score 222, accepted):

If you consider

```
obj.sort().reverse();
```

VS

```
obj.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1))
```

VS

```
obj.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a) )
```

**The performance winner is : `obj.sort().reverse()`.**

> Testing with an array of 10.000 elements,  `obj.sort().reverse()` is faster than `obj.sort( function )` (except on chrome), and `obj.sort( function )` (using `localCompare`).

Performance test here :

```js
var results = [[],[],[]]

for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  const randomArrayGen = () => Array.from({length: 10000}, () => Math.random().toString(30));
  const randomArray = randomArrayGen();
  const copyArray = x => x.slice();

  obj = copyArray(randomArray);
  let t0 = performance.now();
  obj.sort().reverse();
  let t1 = performance.now();

  obj = copyArray(randomArray);
  let t2 = performance.now();
  obj.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1))
  let t3 = performance.now();

  obj = copyArray(randomArray);
  let t4 = performance.now();
  obj.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a))
  let t5 = performance.now();  

  results[0].push(t1 - t0);
  results[1].push(t3 - t2);
  results[2].push(t5 - t4);  
}

const calculateAverage = x => x.reduce((a,b) => a + b) / x.length ;

console.log("obj.sort().reverse():                   " + calculateAverage(results[0]));
console.log("obj.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1)):   " + calculateAverage(results[1]));
console.log("obj.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a)): " + calculateAverage(results[2]));
```

Comment: How does that compare to using `localeCompare`?

Comment: i uodated my answer and the jsperf, to include the `localCompare` case

Comment: Wow - That was impressive!

Comment: the same situation woud be `(a,b)=>b.localeCompare(a))` not `b.localeCompare(a, 'es', {sensitivity: 'base'}))` that is for special characters. `obj.sort().reverse()` doesn't work with special characters

Comment: [`(a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1)` is not enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892652/1048572)

Comment: Node benchmarks on my machine show #2 as being the fastest:   

`obj.sort().reverse():                   3.090556930010207`       

`obj.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1)):   2.7984550699871034`       

`obj.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a)): 10.975987620060332`

Comment: yeah, sort+reverse r both native binary code, while sort+lambda comes with lambda is js code

Comment: `obj.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1))` is both incorrect and slow. Correct version is `obj.sort((a, b) => b - a)` which easily beats #1.

Comment: `obj.sort((a, b) => b - a)` only works for numbers, not strings!

Answer (score 8):

**Using just `sort` and `reverse` `a` > `Z` , that is wrong if you want to order lower cases and upper cases strings:**

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c","A","B","Z"];

arr.sort().reverse();

console.log(arr)//<-- [ 'c', 'b', 'a', 'Z', 'B', 'A' ] wrong!!!
```

English characters

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c","A","B","Z"];

arr.sort((a,b)=>b.localeCompare(a))

console.log(arr)
```

Special characters using [locales](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Using_locales), in this example es (spanish)

```js
var arr = ["a", "á", "b","c","A","Á","B","Z"];

arr.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a, 'es', {sensitivity: 'base'}))


console.log(arr)
```

sensitivity in this case is **base**:

> Only strings that differ in base letters compare as unequal. Examples:
>   a ≠ b, a = á, a = A.

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong? OP asked to make the sorting descending, not to make it case-invariant.

Comment: @Bergi Using `sort` and `reverse` could solve the problem that OP is facing using that specific set of data, it is not good as a general solution in my opinion. Also OP said in the title `strings`, not certain kind of strings. Either way  "is wrong"  is a bad generalization.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to revers the order of sorting is by swapping the operands. In ES2015 that's as easy as `[b, a] = [a, b]`. A full example:

```js
function compareWithOrder(a, b, shouldReverse = false) {
  if (shouldReverse) {
    [b, a] = [a, b]
  }
  return yourComparatorFn(a, b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c","A","B","Z"];

arr.sort((a,b)=>b.localeCompare(a))

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  What are your metrics for efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but an interesting one. This is my solution for a non-special character's input.

```
var arr = ["a","b","c","A","B","Z"];

  console.log(arr.sort((a,b)=> {
      const lastCodeIn = b.toLowerCase().charCodeAt();
      const lastCode = b.charCodeAt();
      const firstCodeIn = a.toLowerCase().charCodeAt();
      const firstCode = a.charCodeAt();

      if(lastCodeIn - firstCodeIn === 0){
        return lastCode - firstCode;
      }
      return lastCodeIn - firstCodeIn;
    })
  );//[ 'Z', 'c', 'b', 'B', 'a', 'A' ]
```

The reason is that ascii code for UPPER case are lower than lower case.