# How can I get the highest 3 values from a json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

So I need to get the highest 3 values from an array, though I don't know how many values I need to check since that number will change periodically, I tried running this loop but it doesn't work.

```
numbers = new array();
numbers = (6,34,6623,22,754,2677,12)
var num1 = 0
var num2 = 0
var num3 = 0
for (var i=0; i<numbers.length;i++) {
    if num1<numbers[i] {
        num1 = numbers[i]
    } else if num2<numbers[i] {
         num2 = numbers[i]
      } else if num3<numbers[i] {
           num3 = numbers[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort the array in descending order and pick first 3 values

Comment: You need square brackets around the array, not parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the other answers propose the correct and fast way to do this, i.e. to `sort` the array in descending order and take the first three elements.

If you're interested why your code did not work: The problem is that you need to keep track of each of the last found `max` values if a new one is found. You need to change your code to something like this:

```js
const numbers = [6, 34, 6623, 22, 754, 2677, 12]
let max = 0;
let oneLowerToMax = 0;
let twoLowerToMax = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   if (numbers[i] > max) {
       twoLowerToMax = oneLowerToMax;
       oneLowerToMax = max;
       max = numbers[i];
   }else if(numbers[i] > oneLowerToMax) {
       twoLowerToMax = oneLowerToMax;
       oneLowerToMax = numbers[i];
   }else if(numbers[i] > twoLowerToMax) {
       twoLowerToMax = numbers[i];
   }
}

console.log(max, oneLowerToMax, twoLowerToMax) // prints 6623, 2677, 754
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array in descending order and then get all 3 element by its index:

```
let numbers = new Array(6,34,6623,22,754,2677,12);
numbers.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

console.log(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a simpler way you can achieve this.
first, run a `sort()` on your array, then pick the highest ones.

```
const myArray = [7,4,99,10,55,1];
console.log(myArray.sort((a,b)=>b-a).slice(0, 3)) // [99, 55, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Simply sort your array in descending order, then slice the first three values.

> Note: `.sort().reverse()` is the speediest approach for sorting in descending order. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52030227/129086

```js
function getTopThree(arr) {
  // spread avoids modifying the original array
  return [...arr].sort().reverse().slice(0, 3);
}

getTopThree(numbers);
```

Whenever your `numbers` array is updated or changed, call `getTopThree(numbers)` again.

Answer (score 1):

you can sort array

```
var numbers = [1,65,8,98,689,12,33,2,3,789];
var topValues = [... numbers].sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,3);
```