# How to pass sort direction to a function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
    this.userActionsRights$ = combineLatest([this.sortBy$, this.userActionsRights$]).pipe(
        map(([sortBy, userRights]) => {
            const { active, direction } = sortBy;
            const sortByAsc = direction === 'asc';
            let sortFn;

            if (active === 'name') sortFn = compareString;
            if (active === 'id') sortFn = compareNumber;

            return userRights.sort(sortFn);
        }),
    );
```

Where compare string is:

```
export function compareString(a: string | undefined, b: string | undefined, isAsc: boolean) {
  if (a === undefined || a === null) return isAsc ? 1 : -1
  if (b === undefined || b === null) return isAsc ? -1 : 1

  return isAsc ? b.localeCompare(a) : a.localeCompare(b)
}
```

How to pass `sortByAsc` to `compareString` and then apply it below in `userRights.sort(sortFn);`.

Comment: I got the problem, I have an array of objects, so I need to sort by object fields name or id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to solve your problem would be to wrap `sortFn` in a function that inverts the result if the sort direction is `"desc"`.

```
const userRights = /* an array */;
const sortFn = /* sort callback function that sorts asc */;
const direction = /* the sort direction */;
```

```
const modifiers = { asc: 1, desc: -1 };

// Forward the `a` and `b` arguments to `sortFn` and multiply the return
// value with the modifier.
return userRights.sort((a, b) => sortFn(a, b) * modifiers[direction]);
```

Note that `direction` must be either `"asc"` or `"desc"`, otherwise `NaN` is returned. (A number multiplied by `undefined` results in `NaN`.)

To allow both uppercase and lowercase characters you might want to downcase the `direction` up front.

```
direction = direction.toLowerCase(); // <- you have to define direction with `let`
```

You probably also want to throw an error if an invalid direction is passed.

```
if (!(direction in modifiers)) {
  throw new Error(`Invalid sort direction "${direction}".`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new arrow function on the fly, like so:

```js
this.userActionsRights$ = combineLatest([this.sortBy$, this.userActionsRights$])
  .pipe(
    map(([sortBy, userRights]) => {
      const { active, direction } = sortBy;
      const sortByAsc = direction === 'asc';
      let sortFn;

      // Here instead of passing the method directly,
      // we create a new one with the correct parameters passed
      if (active === 'name') sortFn = (a, b) => compareString(a, b, sortByAsc);
      if (active === 'id') sortFn = compareNumber;

      return userRights.sort(sortFn);
    }),
  );
```

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: a.localeCompare is not a function`. I get this error on the line: `compareString(a, b, sortByAsc);`

Comment: true, however `.sort().reverse()` is more efficient, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52030227/3393379)

Comment: reverse is not working for numbers

Comment: @Jessy seems like that is a problem stemming from your data. Did you maybe `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` class instances?

Comment: I get always filled array `userRights`. I have checked

Comment: If you want any help, show us your problem. Nobody can help you if you don't show us the code and values @Jessy