# Sorting an Array of objects based on a property as a Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

If I have an array of words...

```
const a = ["abc", "abcd", "xyz"]
```

and I want to sort that array and filter it based off a pattern (ex. "ab") then I can use filter and regex like so... [giving me the array of items which has "ab" at the start of every item in the array"

```
let value = "abc";
let regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`);
const sorted = a.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
```

However, what about this same principle, but instead of an array of items, those items are objects within an array, like so...

```
const b = [
{text: "abc", color: "blue"},
{text: "abcd", color: "red"},
{text: "xyz", color: "yellow"}
]
```

Comment: @Taki `a.text - b.text` won't work

Comment: @Bergi i just remembered that the callback of `sort()` should return a boolean, i used `a.text > b.text` in the answer below

Comment: @Taki No, it should not return a boolean (at least not in JavaScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first `filter()` the array based on the `regex` (there is no need to sort elements that will be filtered later) and then sort it using [String::localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
const arr = [
    {text: "abcd", color: "red"},
    {text: "abc", color: "blue"},
    {text: "xyz", color: "yellow"}
];

let value = "abc";
let regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`);

const sortedArr = arr
    .filter(x => regex.test(x.text))
    .sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text));

console.log(sortedArr);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to tell `.sort()` which property you want to sort with and pass `v.text` to the regex :

```js
const b = [{
    text: "abc",
    color: "blue"
  },
  {
    text: "abcd",
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    text: "xyz",
    color: "yellow"
  }
]

let value = "abc";
let regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`);
const sorted = b.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.text > b.text)
    return 1;
  if (a.text < b.text)
    return -1;
  return 0
}).filter(v => regex.test(v.text));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: [not returning `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883421/1048572) doesn't make it much better...

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function which accepts input array, string, and a function which accepts the current value of `.findIndex()` to sort the resulting array and the string value which is passed  to `RegExp` constructor, where the function parameters can be adjusted to use destructuring assignment to match specific property name within input array of objects, with `.splice()` used to remove matched element from array, or remainder of input array.

```js
const regexSort = (arr, value, fn) => {
  const res = [];
  for (let i; (i = arr.findIndex(v => fn(v, value))) > -1; res.push(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]));
  return [...res, ...arr];
}

const a = ["abc", "abcd", "xyz", "abcdef", "qrst", "abcg"];

const b = [
  {text: "abc", color: "blue"},
  {text: "abcd", color: "red"},
  {text: "xyz", color: "yellow"},
  {text: "abcdef", color: "gold"},
  {text: "qrst", color: "green"},
  {text: "abcg", color: "brown"}
];

let value = "abc";
// array of strings
console.log(
  regexSort(a, value, (key, value) => new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`).test(key))
);
// array of objects, destructure `text` property assign to `key`
console.log(
  regexSort(b, value, ({text: key}, value) => new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`).test(key))
);
```

Answer (score -2):

*(Filtering first may avoid sorting a lot of value that would be discard by filter)*

```js
const b = [
  {text: "abcf", color: "white"},
  {text: "abc", color: "blue"},
  {text: "xyz", color: "yellow"},
  {text: "abcd", color: "red"},
  {text: "abcz", color: "green"},
];


let value = "abc";
let regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`);

const sorted = b
  .filter(item => regex.test(item.text))
  .sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text));
  
 console.log(sorted);
```