# How can i fix the method sort to work properly for my task?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort dates by ascending, but it doesn't sort quite right.

I have tried several different ways to do it. But it keeps on having the same problem.

```
const arr = [
  { date: "01.01.2017", dayOfWeek: "Tuesday" },
  { date: "01.01.2016", dayOfWeek: "Saturday" },
  { date: "01.01.2002", dayOfWeek: "Wednesday" },
  { date: "01.01.2003", dayOfWeek: "Wednesday" }
];
const sort = arr
  .sort((a, b) =>
    new Date(a.date).getTime > new Date(b.date).getTime ? 1 : -1
  )
  .map(function(m) {
    console.log(m.date, m.dayOfWeek);
  });
```

What I expect:

01.01.2002 Wednesday

01.01.2003 Wednesday

16 01.01.2016 Saturday

16 01.01.2017 Tuesday

but  the output I get is this:

01.01.2003 Wednesday

01.01.2002 Wednesday

16 01.01.2016 Saturday

16 01.01.2017 Tuesday

Comment: `getTime` is a function, you need to call it `getTime()`

Comment: Your date strings are not in a format that `new Date()` can parse portably.

Comment: Be careful with these date formats, they're non-standard, so they're not guaranteed to be parsed correctly by the `Date` constructor.

Comment: You don't need to call `getTime`. `Date` objects can be compared directly.

Comment: If you need to parse a non-standard format, you could use `moment.js`.

Comment: [Don't forget to `return 0` in case the two values are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892652/1048572)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getTime` is a function, you need to execute it to actually compare values :

`new Date(a.date).getTime() > new Date(b.date).getTime()? 1 :-1`

Comment: Simpler is to subtract instead of using a ternary.

Comment: `new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost right; you didn't call the function `getTime` of `new Date`.

Note: The best way to sort numbers and dates is by using subtraction.

Note 2: Using `console.log` with `Array.map` will end up with an array of `undefined`.

```js
const arr = [
  { date: "01.01.2017", dayOfWeek: "Tuesday" },
  { date: "01.01.2016", dayOfWeek: "Saturday" },
  { date: "01.01.2002", dayOfWeek: "Wednesday" },
  { date: "01.01.2003", dayOfWeek: "Wednesday" }
].sort(
  (a, b) => new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime()
).forEach(m => {
  console.log(m.date, m.dayOfWeek);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try it without `getTime()` as both are of type Date so they can be compared directly.

```
  const sort = arr
    .sort( (a, b) =>
      new Date(a.date) > new Date(b.date) ? 1 : -1
    )
    .map(function(m) {
      console.log(m.date, m.dayOfWeek);
    });
```