# What's the difference in returning 0 or 1 on a javascript sorting function?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Okay, so I've already read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) about the sort method, and I know what returning a positive, negative or zero number means, but in all my tests, this function:

```
let compareNumbers = (a, b) => {
if (a < b) return -1
return 0
}
```

Always gives me the same result as this one:

```
let compareNumbers = (a, b) => {
if (a < b) return -1
return 1
}
```

And this one:

```
let compareNumbers = (a, b) => {
if (a > b) return 1
if (a < b) return -1
return 0
}
```

Even with some repeated numbers back to back, so I'm just curious if there's any difference in performance or results between those three sorting functions.

Comment: Have a look at [Should every compare function have a “return 0” statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883421/1048572) and [Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572) Do they answer your question?

Comment: It means that you've found a `sort` implementation whose algorithm doesn't distinguish between `0` and `1`, effectively using a `>=` comparator. Or you've just chosen your example input luckily :-)

Comment: In the case of numbers, you will not notice it as `0` means the numbers are equal and don't need to be swapped but when you return `1` it will be. for example if the array is `[5,5]` you will not know after sorting `5`s are swapped or not but actually when you return 0 they will not and with 1 they will be. It will be easier to understand with an object of an array, like `[{a:1, b:5}, {a:2, b:5}]` now sort it comparing b's values.