# Array sorting is broken with Bigint In JS?

Tags: javascript

It seems like `Array.prototype.sort()` is broken with `BigInt`

This works

```
const big = [1n, 2n, 3n, 4n];
big.sort();
console.log(big);
// expected output: Array [1n, 2n, 3n, 4n]
```

But this doesn't :(

```
const big = [1n, 2n, 3n, 4n];
big.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
console.log(big);
//Error: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number
```

or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Comment: I think you mis read the question, it seems compare function only expects integer values in return..

Comment: I believe `BigInt` is handled differently from typical numerical values. You may need to use a separate library that makes working with these types of values much easier to properly subtract the two. I haven't worked with `BigInt` before, but from my limited understanding, that might be the root of the problem.

Comment: You could do `Number(a-b)` but not sure if it's the correct way to handle it. It converts the BigInt  to number. If the difference is more than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2^53 - 1), it will not work

Comment: Found this on Mozilla's website, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Comparisons (in the 3rd code block). It shows that sorting the way you have it is not supported, and offers a way to do what you are looking for.

Comment: found the answer below its working, the illusion is with -1n 0n 1n are within range of integer so compare fn expects it to be in integer and not bigint

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JavaScript sort method requires a function as a parameter that can compare two elements of the array and return either a positive number, or a negative number or zero. Number is the keyword here.

[BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) operations like addition and subtraction returns BigInt type and not a Number type. And that's why the error you are getting.

So, Something like this should do the job

```js
const big = [1n, 2n, 3n, 4n];
big.sort((a ,b) => {
  if(a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a < b){
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
console.log(big);
```

---

Interestingly, [MDN document that I linked to previously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Comparisons), also suggests how to sort an array of BigInts, and it is concise:

Copying the whole section here for posterity:

```js
const mixed = [4n, 6, -12n, 10, 4, 0, 0n]
// ↪  [4n, 6, -12n, 10, 4, 0, 0n]

mixed.sort() // default sorting behavior
// ↪  [ -12n, 0, 0n, 10, 4n, 4, 6 ]

mixed.sort((a, b) => a - b)
// won't work since subtraction will not work with mixed types
// TypeError: can't convert BigInt to number

// sort with an appropriate numeric comparator
mixed.sort((a, b) => (a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0))
// ↪  [ -12n, 0, 0n, 4n, 4, 6, 10 ]
```

Comment: You also need to return 0 when `a === b`

Comment: I *think* that should not matter because what difference would it make it the sort method puts one `2n` before another `2n` or after. Updated the answer, as document says sort should return positive, zero, or negative number.

Comment: [Sorting in JavaScript: Should every compare function have a “return 0” statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883421)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `a - b` in the `sort` callback function will return a BigInt data type, while `sort` expects it to return something that is (or can coerce to) a Number data type.

So you can use `a > b || -(a < b)` as callback expression:

```js
const big = [10n, 9n, 8n, 7n];
big.sort((a, b) => a > b || -(a < b));
console.log(big + ""); // 7,8,9,10
```

Note that the first version (without `sort` callback) does not work in general, because then `sort` will compare the elements as *strings*. It is clear that this can yield results that are not numerically sorted:

```js
const big = [10n, 9n, 8n, 7n];
big.sort(); // string-based sort
console.log(big + ""); // 10,7,8,9 is wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

This might appear to be broken at first but its not, the problem is definition of the compare function is always expecting a return value of -1, 0, 1 and it has no reason to expect bigint of -1 0 1  cause they all are in range of normal int..
so this should solve

```
big.sort((a,b)=>a<b?-1:(a>b?1:0));
```