# Why does sorting an array with toggle producers different descent outcome than without toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```js
const log = console.log;
let toggle = true;
let students = [
    {name: "Alpha", score: 90, school: "East"},
    {name: "Georgia", score: 100, school: "East"},
    {name: "Climent", score: 40, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Elizabeth", score: 80, school: "East"},
    {name: "Filipino", score: 95, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Detroit", score: 75, school: "East"},
    {name: "Beta", score: 90, school: "Wast"},

]


$("#click").click(()=> { 
  let asc = 1;
  toggle? asc = 1 : asc = -1;
  let sorted = students.sort((a, b)=> { 
        let first = a.name;
        let second = b.name;
        return first > second ? asc * 1 : -1
    })

    for(let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) { 
        log(sorted[i])
    }

    toggle = !toggle;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<button id="click">CLICK</button>
```

In here, I am using a variable to change the returned value in order to toggle between negative and positive.

But why is it that, if I instead just use `-1 : -1` for both cases, I'm not getting the same desc outcome as I do with toggle? Aren't they literally the same? The second time you click the button, asc is `-1`, so both are `-1 : -1`, so how is that producing a perfect desc sorting, but if I directly add `-1 : -1`, I get a different result?

```js
const log = console.log;
let toggle = true;
let students = [
    {name: "Alpha", score: 90, school: "East"},
    {name: "Georgia", score: 100, school: "East"},
    {name: "Climent", score: 40, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Elizabeth", score: 80, school: "East"},
    {name: "Filipino", score: 95, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Detroit", score: 75, school: "East"},
    {name: "Beta", score: 90, school: "Wast"},

]


$("#click").click(()=> { 
  let asc = 1;
  toggle? asc = 1 : asc = -1;
  let sorted = students.sort((a, b)=> { 
        let first = a.name;
        let second = b.name;
        return first > second ? -1 : -1
    })

    for(let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) { 
        log(sorted[i])
    }

    toggle = !toggle;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<button id="click">CLICK</button>
```

This produces different outcome from the first one when clicked a second time, and I don't understand why.

I also don't understand why are they even changing in the second case despite both cases always returning -1, so why is the result always different? Shouldn't it be always the same? What am I not getting here..

Comment: Not the main issue, but have a look at [Sorting in JavaScript: Should every compare function have a “return 0” statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883421/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why is it that, if I instead just use -1 : -1 for both cases, I'm not getting the same desc outcome as I do with toggle? Aren't they literally the same?

No, but the reason is *slightly* subtle: The array starts off in a different order, and since the `sort` callback isn't keeping its contract about what it will return, `sort` becomes susceptible to the initial conditions, producing a chaotic result. Remember that `sort` sorts the array *in-place*, it doesn't make a copy, so the result of the first sort (the first click) influences the result of the second sort (the second click), since `students` is in a different order and the `sort` callback isn't doing its job correctly to help `sort` apply total order to the array. It wouldn't matter if the `sort` callback were doing its job, but since it isn't, it does matter.

Here's your first snippet changed to show the order of the array before sorting and to show what entries it's called with during sorting:

```js
const log = console.log;
let toggle = true;
let students = [
    {name: "Alpha", score: 90, school: "East"},
    {name: "Georgia", score: 100, school: "East"},
    {name: "Climent", score: 40, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Elizabeth", score: 80, school: "East"},
    {name: "Filipino", score: 95, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Detroit", score: 75, school: "East"},
    {name: "Beta", score: 90, school: "Wast"},
]

$("#click").click(()=> { 
    let asc = 1;
    toggle? asc = 1 : asc = -1;
    console.log(`Names before sorting: ${students.map(({name}) => name).join(", ")}`);
    let sorted = students.sort((a, b)=> { 
        let first = a.name;
        let second = b.name;
        const result = first > second ? asc * 1 : -1;
        console.log(a.name, b.name, result);
        return result;
    })
    console.log(`Names before sorting: ${students.map(({name}) => name).join(", ")}`);

    toggle = !toggle;
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 80% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<button id="click">CLICK</button>
```

Here's what we see:

First click:

```
Names before sorting: Alpha, Georgia, Climent, Elizabeth, Filipino, Detroit, Beta
Georgia Alpha 1
Climent Georgia -1
Climent Georgia -1
Climent Alpha 1
Elizabeth Climent 1
Elizabeth Georgia -1
Filipino Elizabeth 1
Filipino Georgia -1
Detroit Elizabeth -1
Detroit Climent 1
Beta Elizabeth -1
Beta Climent -1
Beta Alpha 1
Names before sorting: Alpha, Beta, Climent, Detroit, Elizabeth, Filipino, Georgia
```

Second click:

```
Names before sorting: Alpha, Beta, Climent, Detroit, Elizabeth, Filipino, Georgia
Beta Alpha -1
Climent Beta -1
Detroit Climent -1
Elizabeth Detroit -1
Filipino Elizabeth -1
Georgia Filipino -1
Names before sorting: Georgia, Filipino, Elizabeth, Detroit, Climent, Beta, Alpha
```

So going into the second sort, the entries are in the order Alpha, Beta, Climent, Detroit, Elizabeth, Filipino, Georgia.

Here's your second snippet with the same changes:

```js
const log = console.log;
let toggle = true;
let students = [
    {name: "Alpha", score: 90, school: "East"},
    {name: "Georgia", score: 100, school: "East"},
    {name: "Climent", score: 40, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Elizabeth", score: 80, school: "East"},
    {name: "Filipino", score: 95, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Detroit", score: 75, school: "East"},
    {name: "Beta", score: 90, school: "Wast"},
]


$("#click").click(()=> { 
    let asc = 1;
    toggle? asc = 1 : asc = -1;
    console.log(`Names before sorting: ${students.map(({name}) => name).join(", ")}`);
    let sorted = students.sort((a, b)=> { 
        let first = a.name;
        let second = b.name;
        const result = first > second ? -1 : -1;
        console.log(a.name, b.name, result);
        return result;
    })
    console.log(`Names after sorting: ${students.map(({name}) => name).join(", ")}`);

    toggle = !toggle;
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 80% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<button id="click">CLICK</button>
```

The first click produces:

```
Names before sorting: Alpha, Georgia, Climent, Elizabeth, Filipino, Detroit, Beta
Georgia Alpha -1
Climent Georgia -1
Elizabeth Climent -1
Filipino Elizabeth -1
Detroit Filipino -1
Beta Detroit -1
Names after sorting: Beta, Detroit, Filipino, Elizabeth, Climent, Georgia, Alpha
```

Note the random-seeming order of the names at the end: Beta, Detroit, Filipino, Elizabeth, Climent, Georgia, Alpha

The second click:

```
Names before sorting: Beta, Detroit, Filipino, Elizabeth, Climent, Georgia, Alpha
Detroit Beta -1
Filipino Detroit -1
Elizabeth Filipino -1
Climent Elizabeth -1
Georgia Climent -1
Alpha Georgia -1
Names after sorting: Alpha, Georgia, Climent, Elizabeth, Filipino, Detroit, Beta
```

Since the starting point is different, and the `sort` callback is breaking its contract, `sort` produces a chaotic result. Since the initial conditions are different, the result is different.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> I don't understand 3 things:
>
> 1. What do you mean by breaking its contract? What contract are you referring to? Do you mean the default behavior of the sort()?

The "contract" here is what `sort`'s callback is expected to do according to [the specification of `sort`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort):

> If *comparefn* is not undefined, it should be a function that accepts two arguments *x* and *y* and returns a negative Number if *x* < *y*, a positive Number if *x* > *y*, or a zero otherwise.

`sort` relies on the callback to do that in order to do its job. It can't work correctly if (for instance) you return `-1` for `"x"` and `"y"` ("x goes before y"), `-1` for `"y"` and `"z"` ("y goes before z"), **and** `-1` for `"z"` and `"x"` — that's nonsense, z can't go before x if x is before y and y is before z. `sort` can't do its job if the sort callback doesn't do *its* job.

> 2. why does the order of the elements matter? I thought that all the elements are paired with each other in all combinations, so why would the initial order make a difference?

No, that would be a very inefficient sort algorithm. In an efficient sort algorithm, only the minimum number of element combinations necessary to determine the order is compared. (That's an oversimplification; sorting is a hard problem and there are lots of different solutions with differing memory requirements, etc.) If an algorithm has compared `"x"` and `"y"` and learned "x goes before y," and it's compared `"y"` and `"z"` and learned that "y goes before z," it doesn't have to compare `"x"` and `"z"` because it already knows that "x goes before z" (because "x goes before y" and "y goes before z"). (It may end up having to do it anyway; again, sorting is a hard problem and there are lots of different solutions.)

But even if it did do every possible combination, it couldn't possibly reconcile the contradictory information that "x goes before y" and "y goes before z" and "z goes before y".

> 3. Why the second click of first snippet compares fewer combinations of the array elements compared to the first click?

Because the algorithm did all the work that it needed to do, based on the information from the `sort` callback, with just that number of compares. The algorithm didn't have to do more compares, because the information it had told it that was all the compares that were necessary. That information was wrong, of course, and so the result is wrong, but the algorithm **has** to assume what it's being told is the truth.

I recommend reading up on a couple of the more basic [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and perhaps even working through them with your sample set of names and seeing what happens if the answer to the question "is this before that?" is always "yes" even when it doesn't make sense.

---

All of which is by-the-bye. The results you get when the `sort` callback isn't keeping to its contract aren't really important and can vary from JavaScript engine to JavaScript engine (or even version to version) since the specification doesn't require a specific sort algorithm (just specific results). Those algorithms expect the callback to do its job and tell the algorithm what the relative ranking of the two elements given to it are. Giving incorrect information to those algorithms gives you a chaotic result.

Ignoring the second snippet, there are three problems with the `sort` callback in the first snippet; even though it *seems* to work with the data you've provided, it won't work reliably with all inputs. The problems are:

1. It doesn't ever return `0`, but it's expected to do that when the elements are equal. The only reason that's not an issue in your example is that none of the names is the same, but of course with real data, it would matter.
2. You're only using `asc` when returning the "greater" indicator, not when returning the "lesser" indictor, because `asc` is missing from the `:` part of `return first > second ? asc * 1 : -1`. So when `asc` is `-1`, your callback will (as you've observed) always return `-1`. This produces chaotic results.
3. You're using relational operators on strings, which generally doesn't produce correct results except for things written in just the letters `a-z` in English, since they compare character codes, not the appropriate relative lexicographic positions of the strings. Use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare strings in a more appropriate way, so that (for instance) `z` isn't before `é`.

The `sort` callback should be:

```
return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) * asc;
```

Updated snippet:

```js
const log = console.log;
let toggle = true;
let students = [
    {name: "Alpha", score: 90, school: "East"},
    {name: "Georgia", score: 100, school: "East"},
    {name: "Climent", score: 40, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Elizabeth", score: 80, school: "East"},
    {name: "Filipino", score: 95, school: "Wast"},
    {name: "Detroit", score: 75, school: "East"},
    {name: "Beta", score: 90, school: "Wast"},

]


$("#click").click(()=> { 
  // No reason to have to separate assignments
  let asc = toggle ? 1 : -1;
  let sorted = students.sort((a, b)=> { 
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) * asc;
    })

    log("Result:");
    for(let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) { 
        log(sorted[i])
    }

    toggle = !toggle;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<button id="click">CLICK</button>
```

```
return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) * asc;
```

Comment: First click on snippet 1: `return first > second ? asc * 1(1) : asc * -1(-1)`. Second click on snippet 1: `return first > second ? asc * 1(-1) : asc * -1(-1)` both are `-1`. First click on snippet 2: `return first > second ? -1 : -1` both are `-1`. So, different result?

Comment: @IloveCoffee - OMG, how many times did I read past that?!?! Sorry about that. I've updated the answer to explain what's going on there. Fundamentally, though, it really isn't important though I understand why you were curious about it. The key thing is to make sure the `sort` callback keeps to its contract.

Comment: Okay, so I understand your explanation, but I don't understand 3 things: 1) What do you mean by `breaking its contract`? What `contract` are you referring to? Do you mean the default behavior of the `sort()`? 2) why does the order of the elements matter? I thought that all the elements are paired with each other in all combinations, so why would the initial order make a difference? 3) Why the second click of first snippet compares fewer combinations of the array elements compared to the first click?

Comment: I just discovered that, the first time you click, the sorting starts from the first element in the array, but the second time you click, the sorting start from the last element in the array. Why is that? Why is this fundamental information on how sort works not explained anywhere? So annoying.

Comment: @IloveCoffee - I've updated the answer to respond to your 1-3 in your comment above. As for how `sort` works not being explained: it **is** explained. It's explained in the specification I've linked to from the answer. If you want more information for a specific JavaScript engine (since they're allowed to pick their own sorting algorithms), in most cases you can find that information in the source code or documentation for the JavaScript engine (they'r emostly open source). Then there's the reams and reams of documentation on sorting algorithms in computer science literature. ...

Comment: ... But **all** of it, I daresay, starts from the assumption that the algorithms being used won't be lied to. That they won't be told "x" is before "y" and "y" is before "z" but "z" is before "x". That's what the `sort` callback in the question does, which is why the results are nonsensical.

Comment: *"I just discovered that, the first time you click, the sorting starts from the first element in the array, but the second time you click, the sorting start from the last element in the array."* What makes you think that? I don't see that on V8 (the JS engine in Chromium-based browsers). Look at the output I describe in the answer. The first sort starts with `"Georgia"` (the second element) and `"Alpha"` (the first element). The second sort does the exact same thing, it starts with `"Detroit"` (the second element) and `"Beta"` (the first element). Remember, again, the array has changed.

Comment: I just realized something else that perplexes me and I can't understand. If I add `asc` to both cases, like this `return first > second ? asc * 1 : asc * -1` then that means, the second time I click, I will have this `-1 : 1`, but then why am I getting a descent order? `Beta Alpha 1`  - `Climent Beta 1` -  `Detroit Climent 1` -  `Elizabeth Detroit 1`  - `Filipino Elizabeth 1` -  `Georgia Filipino 1` if the sorting starts from the last element, or last pair, then this does not produce a descending order! How does this work!? So frustrating.

Comment: @IloveCoffee - *"if the sorting starts from the last element, or last pair"* I don't see anything to suggest that. *"then this does not produce a descending order!"* Sure it does. The callback has said that Alpha comes after Beta, that Beta comes after Climent, that Detroit comes after Elizabeth, that Elizabeth comes after Filipino, and Filipino comes after Georgia. In every case, we've said the one earlier in the alphabet comes after the one later in the alphabet. That's a descending sort. Please read up on sorting algorithms. Note that the order of calls may not seem to make any sense.

Comment: Right.. sorry, I made a mistake here. I assumed when the outcome is `true`, the returned value is `1`, but it's actually `-1` since the first is `-1` the second click. So, I struggle to see the point of having this `return first > second ? asc * 1 : asc * -1` as oppose to just this `return first > second ? asc * 1 :  -1` since on second click, all the returned values are `true`, so I get `-1`, and on third click, on each comparison, the returned value is always `false` so it should return `-1` to get an ascend.

Comment: By the way, are you saying the comparison starts from the first element? When I console.log the `first` and `second` variables before the comparison, I get this `Beta Alpha` - `Climent Beta` - `Detroit Climent` - `Elizabeth Detroit` - `Filipino Elizabeth` - `Georgia Filipino` and then the result is a descending sort `Georgia Filipino Elizabeth Detroit Climent Beta Alpha`, so since it starts with `Georgia`, therefore the comparison starts from the last element. Is that not correct?