# Javascript: array as useEffect depencendy

Tags: javascript, arrays, use-effect

```
useEffect(() => {
    changeColumnsState(mapOrder({array: columnsState, order: columnOrder, key: 'name'}))
  }, [JSON.stringify(columnOrder)])
```

What is the best way to check if array changed? Not length, but order
`columnOrder` is array of numbers.

```
export const ColumnsCustomizeModalForm: FunctionComponent<
  ColumnsCustomizeModalFormProps
> = ({ columns, onClose, modalProps }) => {
  const columnInitial = columns.map((column) => column.name)
  const [columnOrder, setColumnOrder] =
    useState<string[]>(columnInitial)

  const [columnsState, changeColumnsState] = useState(mapOrder({array: columns, order: columnOrder, key: 'name'}))

  useEffect(() => {
    changeColumnsState(mapOrder({array: columnsState, order: columnOrder, key: 'name'}))
  }, [JSON.stringify(columnOrder)])

  const setColumnVisibility = (name: string) => {
    const newColumnsState = columnsState.map((column) => {
      if(column.name === name) {
        return {...column, isHidden: !column.isHidden}
      }
      return column
    })
    changeColumnsState(newColumnsState)
  }

  return (
    <ColumnsCustomizationModalView
      columns={columnsState}
      handleChangeOrder={setColumnOrder}
      handleColumnVisibility={setColumnVisibility}
      handleClose={onClose}
      modalProps={modalProps}
    />
  )
}
```

```
export const mapOrder = <ObjectType, KeyType extends keyof ObjectType>({array, order, key}: {array: ObjectType[], order: ObjectType[KeyType][], key: KeyType}) => {
    const sortedArray = array.sort( function (a, b) {
      var A = a[key], B = b[key];
      
      if (order.indexOf(A) > order.indexOf(B)) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    });
    return sortedArray;
  };
```

Comment: Is `columnOrder` a state?

Comment: @Andy const [columnsState, changeColumnsState] = useState(mapOrder({array: columns, order: columnOrder, key: 'name'}))

Comment: It's the change in state that you should be using. Maybe try `[columnsState.order]`.

Comment: Please show us the whole component, and describe the desired behaviour. E.g. why are you even using `useEffect` instead of `useMemo`?

Comment: Can you show what `mapOrder` does? And it's not clear why you use a separate `columnOrder` state at all, it seems you could simply store this information via the order of objects in the `columnsState` array. So just provide a `setColumnOrder` function that will reorder the `columnsState`, and drop the `columnOrder` state and the effect altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to check if array changed?

The best way is not to check at all. You don't need that `columnOrder` array state and an initialisation and an effect depending on it. Just directly set the order of your `columnsState` array in the handler function:

```
export const ColumnsCustomizeModalForm: FunctionComponent<
  ColumnsCustomizeModalFormProps
> = ({ columns, onClose, modalProps }) => {
  const [columnsState, changeColumnsState] = useState(columns);

  const setColumnOrder = (columnOrder: string[]) => {
    changeColumnsState(array => mapOrder({array, order: columnOrder, key: 'name'}))
  };

  const setColumnVisibility = (name: string) => {
    changeColumnsState(cols => cols.map(column => {
      if (column.name === name) {
        return {...column, isHidden: !column.isHidden}
      }
      return column
    }));
  };

  return (
    <ColumnsCustomizationModalView
      columns={columnsState}
      handleChangeOrder={setColumnOrder}
      handleColumnVisibility={setColumnVisibility}
      handleClose={onClose}
      modalProps={modalProps}
    />
  );
}
```

Also fix your `mapOrder` function to create a new array (and [use correct comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883421/1048572)):

```
export function mapOrder<ObjectType, KeyType extends keyof ObjectType>({array, order, key}: {array: ObjectType[], order: ObjectType[KeyType][], key: KeyType}) {
    return array.slice().sort((a, b) =>
//              ^^^^^^^^
        order.indexOf(a[key]) - order.indexOf(b[key])
    );
}
```

Comment: in that case my order changes only after I call `setColumnVisibility` again. I use react-dnd inside `ColumnsCustomizationModalView`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*call `setColumnVisibility` again*"? Calling it once is enough.

Comment: Does anything in `ColumnsCustomizationModalView` call `setColumnOrder` and `setColumnVisibility` together?

Comment: so when I call `setColumnVisibility` it works. When I drag-n-drop with calling  `setColumnOrder` it changes state, but don't rerender. But when I call `setColumnVisibility` again, it change visibility flag and rerender according to new order state.

Comment: "*it changes state, but don't rerender*" - I don't see how that could happen. Maybe [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you post the code of `ColumnsCustomizationModalView`.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-river-er5r9y?file=/src/Container.tsx:910-1201 
maybe this will help in some way. But I don't use immutability-helper

Comment: I see possible reason but can't understand why. So I put console.log in `mapOrder` function and it return correct updated order. But when I put console.log inside `ColumnsCustomizationModalView` I don't see it. So that component don't rerender. But why it thinks that props didn't change?

Comment: As I said, it might call both functions at once, which would have a closure over the old value, and the last call will win. See the update to my answer that uses the callback style for state setters.

Comment: I used your code. Even `console.log('columnsState', columnsState)` in that component isn't called again. However `mapOrder` returns correct ordered array

Comment: `changeColumnsState(array => ([...mapOrder({array, order: columnOrder, key: 'name'})]))`
I think the reason that we should return new array, but 
it will rerender infinitely

Comment: Oh right, that's the problem: `mapOrder` does not return a new array, it just mutates its input, which will cause React to drop the update - it's still the *same* value.